# Should I replace UITabbarController with my custom UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I don't know how difference between two class if I create tab with custom UIpageViewController I will have more customizable things.

Can someone told me how difference about them ? And If I change to custom uipageviewcontroller what things that I have to aware?

Comment: Totaly depends on your use case and the UI you are going to make, would be better if you share a picture of what you are trying to make.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya Thank you for your reply, My UI like almost like Instagram.

Comment: If your functionality is also just like Instagram (i.e no custom animation) or resizing of the tab bar (dynamic height) then using UITabbarController is better. As many things will be self managed

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya Nice, Thank you so much for reply. :D